# Is there a limit for how many updated records an "for update" trigger can handle?

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers, database-trigger, eventtrigger

I am using Sql Server 2012 and I have a table that receives between 1000-1500 row updates per minute (amount seen in the Activity Monitor - Recent Expensive Queries). This updates come from Gps devices in different locations and the number seems about right (each line represents an active gps device sending updates).

I have wrote an extremely simple "for update trigger" after failing with more complex ones. The simple trigger doesn't seem to work either. The trigger should insert value "1" into a table ("Test") for each row updated in the table receiving the updates ("LiveInfo").

After creating and enabling the trigger I have observed the following:
- no records are inserted in the Test table (as i should have had a record containing value "1" for each row updated)
- it seems like the table LiveInfo (the one receiving the high number of updates) stops receiving updates when the trigger starts.

I have created tables and a trigger with the exact same structure on a local instance of SQLServer (although version 2016) and I tested everything with manual updates instead of automatic updates.
Everything seems to work fine using the simple trigger (even with way more complicated triggers).

The trigger code:

```
Create trigger t_Live
on [Accounting].[dbo].[LiveInfo]
for update
as
Begin
    insert into Test
        (TestUpdate)
    values(1)
End
```

The different versions of SQL Server should not matter for such a simple trigger (from what I have researched) and I start to believe there might be too many updates (or maybe different rows being updated in almost exactly same time) for the trigger to handle.

If anyone has an idea why the trigger does not react to the updates and stops the updates all together would be a great help.

Edit: this is the code that updates the LiveInfo table. I got the query from Activity Monitor and has around 1300 Executions/Min:

```
UPDATE LiveInfo SET
    [LogTimeUTC] = @logTimeUTC,
    [Latitude] = @lat,
    [Longitude] = @lon,
    [Height] = @height,
    [SolutionType] = @solType,
    [TrackedSats] = @trackedSats,
    [PDOP] = @pdop,
    [MountPointName] = @mountPointName,
    [FixedBEIDOU] = @fixedBEIDOU,
    [FixedQZSS] = @fixedQZSS,
    [FixedIRNSS] = @fixedIRNSS
WHERE [LoginWithOrganization] = @loginWithOrg
```

Comment: No, a trigger can handle any number of rows, there is no limit (note that triggers are not fired on Bulk Operations, but that has nothing to do with the number of rows). I think the problem here is that you think a trigger "fires" once per row affected; it doesn't. A trigger "fires" once per DML statement. That means, for your trigger, if someone updates 1, 100, or 1 Million rows in the table `t_live`, in a single statement, only **1** row will be inserted into the table `Test`.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the answer. I was thinking the same regarding the DML statement so I tried to do a count of how many rows the "inserted" table has and just insert that value in my "Test" table. Unfortunately i get nothing inserted when implemented in Production, although works fine in my test environment.

Comment: If nothing is inserted, then nothing was updated; especially with a simple statement like that. you'll need to provide an example that replicates the issue.

Comment: It looks like nothing is updated in the trigger , but If I manualy run a select query on my LiveInfo table every 5 second I can see the rows beeing updated and not all of them at the same time. This make me believe that the update is per row.

Comment: No, a table trigger fires once per DML statement. That is how SQL server is designed. [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9867c3a1695b5f4dcd713ca714313f07)

Comment: Notice, in my example, that there are 3 rows, not 22. Notice, also, that the values are the number of rows that were updated (as a `COUNT` of the number of rows in `inserted` was inserted into table `T`). This proves that the trigger fired 3 times (once for each DML statement), and that it had **all** the rows effected in the object `inserted` for that DML statement.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: I am looking now at the query that updates the table LiveInfo:  UPDATE LiveInfo SET [LogTimeUTC] = "at"logTimeUTC,
          [Latitude] = "at"lat,
          "[Longitude] = "at"lon,
          "[Height] = "at"height,....,More rows Where [LoginWithOrganization] = "at"loginWithOrg. Loginwithorganization is a unique value in the table. I got this query from the Activity Monitor and it has 1239 executions/minute. (sorry for the bad formatting). PS: "at" as in variable sign .

Comment: Comments are not the place for code or important information to your question. i can't read that. Please edit your question with the information.

Comment: sorry for that. is updated now